# Bootstrap Datepicker preview date picked on date click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

im having some trouble with bootstrap datepicker. The thing is that in my program user can pick more than one date, and when they do that, the textbox cant preview all of the data picked. I want something like everytime they pick one date, new textbox or label with the date picked is dynamically shown. How can i achieve this? Thankyou

Here is my datepicker code:

```
               <div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { style = "background-color: #fff;", id = "date", @Class = "form-control input-sm", required = "required", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Date", new { style = "color: red" })

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {

                        $('#datetimepicker').datepicker({
                            multidate: true,
                            multidateSeparator: ",",
                            maxViewMode: 1,
                            datesDisabled: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.dis)],
                            orientation: "bottom left",
                            keyboardNavigation: false,
                            clearBtn: true,
                            daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
                            endDate: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.enddate),
                            startDate: '+2d'

                        });

                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: First I'd remove the MVC code and replace w/ actual rendered HTML. If I understand your question correctly, you have ONE datepicker, and every time the user selects a date, another `textbox/label` appends to the list that holds all of the selections (whether it be 0 or more)?

Comment: Yes its like that, but actually i want every time user select a date, another textbox/label with ONLY that date appends. So if user pick 3 date, there will be 3 appended textbox/label. Can you help me? thankss

Comment: check this is OK - https://jsfiddle.net/04L049pr/2/